# Type error when testing async action creator, I don't understand the difference between the creator and the unit mock

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-typescript

So I have an action creator that creates an API call to the openWeather website, I want to test this creator but when setting up mock test, the store and thunk; I get a type error that I am unsure of.

My action creator:

```
type Effect = ThunkAction<void, State, unknown, WeatherActions>

export const fetchWeatherData = (city: string): Effect => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(`${URL}${city}&appid=${API}`)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log('res', resp)
        dispatch(weatherSuccess(resp.data))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('err', err)
        dispatch(loadingError(err))
      })
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw Error(`Network Error: ${e}`)
  }
}
```

My action creator test setup:

```
jest.mock('axios')

const initialState = {}
type State = typeof initialState

const middleware = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureStore<State, ThunkDispatch<State, unknown, AnyAction>>(middleware)
const store = mockStore(initialState)

describe('Testing api action creator', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    store.clearActions()
  })

  it('#loading', async () => {
    await store.dispatch(fetchWeatherData('peterborough'))
  })

})
```

This is the error that aligns over 'fetchWeatherData('peterborough')' in the above statement:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error by providing store with the proper state type, my state isn't expecting an empty object but the explicit type given to the store as initial state in the reducer.